# How to resolved Combine external JavaScript file issue in asp.net mvc . I am using bundling for render java script file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

[error file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXMr7.jpg)

There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider combining them into as few files as possible.
7 JavaScript resources served from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

From the snapshot provided i see you are in debug mode (localhost). MVC bundler is only bundling individual files when your project is in release mode (debug=false in web.config). This ensures that you can access your individual js files while debugging with browser dev tools.

Comment: In my project i  selected release mode and (debug=false in web.config)but (in bundle config set  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true ) so how could i send one request for all js file to resolved issue plz help.

Comment: Please provide example of your bundle config and the part where you are invoking script rendering (Scripts.Render("...")

Comment: Please show the 7 Javascript files, and how you are adding them to the page.

Comment: rendering on view   @section scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/sheepItPlugin/js", "~/twbsPagination", "~/daterangepicker/js", "~/nod/js")}

Comment: in bundling.confg file   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bloodhound/js").Include("~/Scripts/bloodhound.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/sheepItPlugin/js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.sheepItPlugin-1.1.1.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/fullcalendar/js").Include("~/assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/nod/js").Include("~/Scripts/nod.min.js"));

Comment: Every bundle you use contains only single js file. The idea behind bundling is to put related files to specific bundles. If each of your bundles has only one file - bundling is useless. Browser tools are checking how many different JS files are requested from the client and in total you have 7 different js files from the same localhost domain. Try to put all four scripts used in @section scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/sheepItPlugin/js", "~/twbsPagination", "~/daterangepicker/js", "~/nod/js")} into the single bundle. You should see the difference.

Comment: hi andrius ,when i rendering two group bundling on same page then also gives the same error what should i do now.

Comment: in bundling one group 1)  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/datetime").Include("~/assets/js/date-time/bootstrap-datepicker_ver-8Dec2014.js",
                        "~/assets/js/date-time/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js", "~/assets/js/date-time/moment.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/clockface.js"
                        )); 2)     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/dataTables/js").Include("~/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                       "~/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js"));

Comment: on view @Scripts.Render("~/datetime", "~/dataTables/js") the also give same error Combine external JavaScript (2)

Comment: This error will appear all the time, until you put all scripts into single bundle. I don't think you should take this error very seriously. Sometimes it is not worth to bundle all separate scripts into single bundle, because it depends on your actual scenario.

Comment: thank you andrius sir, i solved my issue  using SquishIt  in ASP.NET MVC .  but  is it good way to do. thank you.